# File processing with C# and MassTransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have read a lot about MassTransit and experimented with it. But I have a scenario which I don't know MassTransit is suitable for it or not. I would appreciate it if someone with a good knowledge of MT would advice me in this matter.

1- I have to process CSV files with 5 different layouts or data structure.

2- Each file could have a million lines.

3- The lines should be processed in order (FIFO). Because the order is important.

4- Proccessing a line consists of multiple steps like, getting related info from DB, check, calculating, analysing and saving to DB.

5- I have my own line-object to pass through different steps in the pipeline and don't want serialization-deserialization of my line-object by MassTransit.

6- I should be able to enable-disable my own middleware in a pipeline easily.

7- Each middleware could have iets own unique configuration information.

8- It should process around 10000 lines per second without the time spend in my middlewares with a normal computer. Like Intel i7 Quad Core, 8GB RAM, SSD. So the throughput should be around 10000 messages per second.

Is MassTransit suitable for this scenario?

For example,

by making 5 different client-consumer windows services with Quartz-MT integration, so each consumer will process a different file.

Each file goes through in-memory pipeline, I'll add a few MT-middlewares for my own line processing steps in the pipeline and when all lines gets processed, mark the file as processed and wait for new files.

I know I can spend a week to build a prototype and try to test it by myself, but I was hoping to hear some advice from the experts to know if I am using the right tool the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no one has responded in recent weeks to my question. Meanwhile, I myself have experimented a little and I found out that MassTransit is not suitable for this job.
As far as I can see, there are a few reasons for this:

1- Performance, performance and performance. This alone is a showstopper for me.
I changed many time different configurations, but never got more than 50 line/second!
In default configuration, it was even less than 5 line/second!

There were only 5 steps and each step did only two simple calculation.
The exact same steps without MassTransit could process almost 15000 line/second.

2- Serialization is a must and there is no way of disabling it. I guess this is one of the reasons that it is so slow.

These reasons were enough to forget masstransit and find other solution.